# rank of m by n-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is spanned by $\def\R{\Bbb R}\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}\subset\R^m$ and $W$ is spanned by $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}\subset\R^n$ with $m \geq 3$ and $n\geq3$. If $V$ is of dimension two, and $W$ is of dimension three, then what is the rank of the $m$ by $n$-matrix $A$ defined by $A=v_1w_1^T +v_2w_2^T +v_3w_3^T$?

I know that one of the $v$'s can be represented as linear combination of other two, and $w$'s are linearly independent, and I don't know what to do next. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can rewrite that sum as a sum of two matrices of rank 1, hence, of rank 2 at most. Shouldn't be too hard to show the hypotheses imply rank exactly 2.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment, AAB, or on the answer posted yesterday?

Comment: I forgot to comment you, and now I understand the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B$ be the $m\times 3$ matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2,v_3$, and $C$ the $3\times n$ matrix whose rows are $w_1^T,w_2^T,w_3^T$; then $A=BC$. Now the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ tell you that the rank of $B$ is $2$ and the rank of $C$ is $3$. Then the linear map $\def\R{\Bbb R}\R^n\to\R^3$ given by $C$ has rank$~3$ and is therefore surjective, and it follows that the rank of the composite map $\Bbb R^n\to\R^3\to\R^m$ given by $BC=A$ equals the rank of $B$, that is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\ v\ $ is an arbitrary member of $\ V\ $, then $\ v = x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 + x_3v_3\ $.  Since $ w_1, w_2, w_3\ $ are linearly independent, the matrix $ \mathcal{W}=\pmatrix{w_1^T\\ w_2^T\\ w_3^T}\ $ has rank $\ 3\ $, and there must exist a vector $\ \mathcal{w}\in\mathbb{R}^n\ $ such that $\ \mathcal{Ww}=\pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3}\ $.  Then $\ A\mathcal{w}=v_1w_1^T\mathcal{w}+ v_2w_2^T\mathcal{w}+ v_3w_3^T\mathcal{w}\ = x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3= v\ $.  So what can you conclude about the columnspace of $\ A\ $?